# sed command in bash input and output file

Tags: unix, sed, command

Does anyone know what this means?

```
sed -e 's/\r$//' inputfile > outputfile
```

This is what I have so far:

`\r` refers to Carriage Return (CR)

so possibly Swap the blanks for Return Carriage? in the inputfile?
I'm not too sure really

Answer (score 2):

It's changing files from `CRLF`-terminated lines into `LF`-terminated lines. The former tend to be Windows-type files where each line ends with a carriage-return/linefeed (`CRLF` or `\r\n`).

UNIX-type files just have a newline character (`LF` or `\n`).

Specifically, that `sed` command substitutes `\r` at the end of a line (indicated by `$`) with nothing, the same as `s/xyzzy/plugh/` would change the first `xyzzy` in the line into `plugh`.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is the name of the program you call.

`-e` tells sed that the following argument is the expression to run.

`s/\r$//` is a substitution: it tells sed to replace carriage return at the end of line (`$`) with nothing. Sed does that for each line.

`inputfile` is the file from which sed reads its input.

`>` is a redirection operator, it means the output of sed will be redirected to `outputfile`.

Basically, the result should be the same as `dos2unix` (sometimes renamed to `fromdos`).

Comment: Thank You. 
Do you know what the difference is with this one then?
sed -e 's/$/\r/' inputfile > outputfile
I would guess it tells said to replace carriage return with a blank space?

Comment: @user3576917: No. it replaces end of line (`$`) with a carriage return (`\r`). See `unix2dos` or `todos` for alternatives.